# Restrict tabbing for all tabbable children in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#input{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Item 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputClass">
    <div id="input">Some text</div>
    <div id="input"><input type="text"></div>
  </div>
   <div>
    <input type="radio">
     <label>Item 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above HTML snippet, is there any way I can restrict tabbing to the `input` inside `.inputClass`?

Please note that in the actual code I have no way of knowing if `.inputClass` will hold an `input` box or not. It could be a button, dropdowns etc or any other tabbable element. So I can't apply `tabindex=-1` to the element(s).

Also, please note I don't want a jQuery solution.

Comment: Would a JavaScript solution be acceptable?

Comment: _“is there any way I can restrict tabbing to the input inside .inputClass?”_ - why? To make the rest of the page practically inaccessible via keyboard navigation …?

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll Yes absolutely!

Comment: @CBroe It would only make the input inaccessible via keyboard. In fact you can take it a step further and disable access to the last radio button as well.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty then what exactly stops you from applying tabindex=-1 to the element?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty I think CBroe's point is that keyboard inaccessibility is a problem because it makes your product totally unusable were A11Y is concerned. If someone needed to use a keyboard instead of a mouse for input, they would have to stop and call tech support or have someone else perform this part of the interaction for them. If A11Y is not a concern for you here, that's fine (everyone's use case is different), but it's important to be aware of the potential ramifications of your design choices.